# Is there a way to make sure only one systemd@.service instance is running resp. gets started

Tags: systemd

I would like to use one .service file for starting a service from varying directories but it would be nice if there was a way to automatically stop any running instance with a different instance name (or even the same) or at least to prevent starting a second instance.

Say I have a unit file `special_service@.service` that contains

```
WorkingDirectory=/var/special_service/%i
```

and then call `systemctl start special_service@try_one` and later I issue `systemctl start special_service@try_two` then this second instance should either fail to start with an appropriate message or even better stop `special_service@try_one` and start `special_service@try_two`.

Comment: I think the basic use case for @ services is to support *independent* instances. If you want to get more magic, you should probably use `ExecStartPre` or similar.

Comment: You probably need to adjust an environment variable with systemctl.

Answer (score 2):

systemd itself has no such possibilities. You may wrap your binary in a shell script which creates/detects a lockfile, and write an extra shell script which removes it (to run on `ExecStopPost=`).

Just remember to `exec` the real binary at the end, in order to not leave an extra bash process hanging around.

Answer (score 0):

I needed something similar, ended up with having two service files.

Instead of having the functionality in `special_service@.service`, I put it to `special_service_impl@.service`.

Then I create `special_service@.service` that has:

```
ExecSartPre=systemctl stop special_service_impl@*
ExecStart=systemctl start special_service_impl@%i
```

In systemd 244 this seems to work so far.